# Yasnippet, Sweave: How to make snippets work from .Rnw files?

Tags: emacs, sweave

I use `yasnippet`'s defined in `~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets/text-mode/latex-mode` to insert small pieces of code when working with LaTeX. I recently started to use Sweave and therefore work on `.Rnw` files. However, I noticed that the (ya)snippets don't work anymore - hitting `TAB` after a trigger word just does not expand the defined snippet. Instead, nothing happens. I thought that's a simple problem to solve, just copy the snippets to `~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets/text-mode/rnw-mode` or `.../noweb-mode`. But that did not work either (meaning that hitting `TAB` does not expand trigger words). What I can do, however, is `M-x yas/expand` right after the trigger word, so it's working, but just not with `TAB`.

How can I use yasnippets from .Rnw files?

**Update 1**

I found http://groups.google.com/group/smart-snippet/browse_thread/thread/8206a23037f598b1/39ed819692df63ad?lnk=gst&q=rnw#39ed819692df63ad
I have exactly that problem -- `<tab>` is bound by noweb-mode. However, the solution posted in the last post does not work for me/does not seem to have an effect on the problem (so, as above, `TAB`-expansion of trigger words does not work).

As described in that post, the mode changes from LaTeX to noweb depending on where the point is in the .Rnw file. I only need my LaTeX macros to expand when in LaTeX mode (of course).

In case this matters, I work with Emacs 24 on Mac OS X 10.7.3.

**Update 2**

`C-h k TAB` leads to (either with or without the solution posted on the above line):

```
<tab> runs the command noweb-indent-line, which is an interactive Lisp function
in `noweb-mode.el'.

It is bound to <tab>.

(noweb-indent-line)

Indent the current line according to mode, after narrowing to this chunk.
```

So obviously, `TAB` is used by noweb.

**Update 3**

When the point is in a LaTeX part of the .Rnw file, then the modes displayed in the mode line are: LaTeX/MP Ref Fly yas pair vl Wrap Fill Noweb NWFL. If the point is in an R chunk of the file, then the modes are: ESS[S] [none] Rox Fly ElDoc pair vl Wrap Noweb NWFL. So indeed, the modes change when out of/within R chunks. However, I still can't `TAB`-expand snippets. My `.emacs` contains (which is obviously not working as expected):

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
  '(lambda ()
     (make-variable-buffer-local 'yas/trigger-key)
     (setq yas/trigger-key [tab])))
```

Comment: It would help if you for both tried methods include what happened and what you expected to happen.

Comment: With "does not work" I mean "it does nothing on hitting `TAB`". So I have a snippet `align` which expands to an `align*`-environment. If I type `align` and hit `TAB`, nothing is expanded. What I can do is `M-x yas/expand` and then the `align*`-environment is expanded, but just `TAB` does not work anymore as described in the post under **Update**

Comment: Please include that in your question instead by editing it. Makes it easier for others to find it. Would binding `yas/expand` to another key than Tan in rnw- and noweb-mode suffice?

Comment: Okay, I added it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem is solved. One needs to switch to the `tighter-tab` branch of `yasnippet`. See https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/231 for more details